# Unity event listeners receiving the event notification at different times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I am trying to have multiple objects respond to a game pause state, this works fine when first running the scene however after restarting the scene the listeners are responding at different times.

**The event that sends the message is:**

```
globalGameState = newState;
GameStateChanged?.Invoke(globalGameState);
```

**And the listener:**

```
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Globals.GameStateChanged += GetStateChange;
        _correctState = false;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Globals.GameStateChanged -= GetStateChange;
    }

    void GetStateChange(GlobalGameState state)
    {
        if (state == _compareState) { _correctState = true; return; }
        _correctState = false;
    }
```

I have checked and made sure that all the objects are subscribing / unsubscribing to the event correctly, I just cant find what would cause it to stop working only when the scene has been restarted. (The scene restart is a simple SceneManager.LoadScene();)

**Debug messages**

[Before scene reload:] https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUDjl.png

[After scene reload:] https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Tla.png

In the second image there are 8 that run on a different timer, every pause or restart after that it is always the same 8 that are de-synced. Restarting unity changes the number in the de-sync batch.

Any idea as to why some are receiving the event on a different timer is welcome.

Comment: Where are you registering the Events OnEnable() and OnDisable()?  Is it in the constructor or the load method?  Maybe the OnDisable() Event is not registered.

Comment: OnEnable(), OnDisable() are both part of the default constructor. And I have debugged finding that all objects are calling both methods correctly.

Comment: If you are running asyn (parallel threads) you could have two starting before one stopping.  You may need to use a WaitHandle to make sure two do not occur at same time : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/eventwaithandle?force_isolation=true

Comment: I had a look into that solution, there should be no asyn happening and didn't seem to work, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you have multiple clients connected at same time you cannot control when you get a request for each client.  The client are sending async.  You cannot stop that from happening.